# Is it a bad practice to declare Widget variables inside the build?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

Hello community I have some widgets that are very simple and in my opinion it would not benefit to create separate stateless widgets for them, but if I need to move them or put them somewhere else in certain circumstances. It is good practice to declare them as a variable in the build. Attached is an example

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget title = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        if (isLargeScreen)
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: Navigator.of(context).pop,
                child: Icon(
                  ...
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        else
          Container(
            margin: ...,
            width: ...,
            height: ...,
            decoration:...,
          ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: ...,
            child: Text(
             ...
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    Widget paragraph = Padding(
      padding: UIPadding.paddingH16,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            ...
            ),
          ),
          Spacing.spacingV8,
          Text(
            formatCurrency.format(
              ....
            ),
            style: ...,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    Widget acceptButton = Button(
      buttonType:...
      text: 'some text'
      onPressed:
         ....
    );
    return isLargeScreen
        ? Material(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
             ...
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 376,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ...,
                  title,
                  paragraph,
                  const Spacer(),
                  Divider(
                    color: ...,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: ..., 
                    child: acceptButton,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
             ...,
              Modal(
               ...
                footerActions: <Widget>[acceptButton],
              ),
            ],
          );
  }
```

I would like to know what you think or if you know anything in the documentation that talks about this. Keep in mind that they are not functions they are variables in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring widget variables inside the `build` method in Flutter is generally not recommended due to potential performance issues and reduced code readability. It's better to declare widget variables at the class level and initialize them outside `build` for improved performance and code organization.

Answer (score 0):

Using separate widgets instead of helper methods is the way to go as they prevent unnecessary widget rebuilds and you will also have clean, maintainable code. Flutter has a   great video explaining why. [link](https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo?si=Zcb0OEN2AhxFM0kE)